# Getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource

I have tried many ways but the error still persists. This error is shown because the location of the image is null but I think there are some more issues that causes this error

I am attaching my code where I got this error  [Code where I got the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGS7r.png)

Comment: The result of `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/second.png")` is returning a `null`, indicating that the resource does not exist.  I might encourage the use of `Class#getResource` instead, but I can't say if that would generate a different result. I don't use eclipse, so I'm not familiar with how resources should be setup so that they are embedded properly during the building/development phases

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"but I can't say if that would generate a different result"* The method the OP is using was never intended for *application* resources. While I cannot guarantee it would have a different result, I'd never call it within my own code.

Comment: BTW OP: Don't post images of code or exceptions. Instead copy/paste the text and use code formatting (select the text and click the little `{}` button above the question [edit] area).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.